Deploying azure function app in vnet gives internal server error
In Azure, when I deploy an azure functions app inside a vnet, I get an internal server error in azure.
When I do the same deployment, but leave out the virtualNetworkSubnetId setting in the function app, it works fine.
I cannot find what is wrong with this bicep template. I also tried using ARM, but that makes no difference.
The hosting plan tier is Flex Consumption (FC1).
If it's handy, I can also give the whole pipeline, but stack overflow is already complaining there is too much code in my question ;)
The content of my bicep file is:
param productName string = 'funcapptest'
param environment string = 'dev'
param location string = 'North Europe'
param managedIdentityName string = 'mi-${productName}-${environment}'

param vnetResourceName string = 'vnet-${productName}-${environment}'
param resourceNameNsgBusiness string = 'nsg-${productName}-business-${environment}'
param resourceNameSubnetBusiness string = 'subnet-${productName}-business-${environment}'
param vnetAddressPrefix string = '10.0.0.0/16'
param subnetPrefixBusiness string = '10.0.1.0/24'

param storageAccountName string = 'sa${productName}${environment}'

param functionAppName string = 'fa-${productName}-${environment}'
param planName string = 'asp-${productName}-${environment}'

resource managedIdentity 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2023-01-31' = {
  name: managedIdentityName
  tags: {
    Environment: environment
    Application: productName
  }
  location: location
}

resource nsgBusiness 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups@2024-01-01' = {
  name: resourceNameNsgBusiness
  tags: {
    Environment: environment
    Application: productName
  }
  location: location
}
resource vnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2024-01-01' = {
  name: vnetResourceName
  tags: {
    Environment: environment
    Application: productName
  }
  location: location
  properties: {
    addressSpace: {
      addressPrefixes: [
        vnetAddressPrefix
      ]
    }
    enableDdosProtection: false
    enableVmProtection: false
  }  
}
resource subnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets@2024-03-01' = {
  parent: vnet
  name: resourceNameSubnetBusiness
  properties: {
    addressPrefix: subnetPrefixBusiness
    networkSecurityGroup: {
      id: nsgBusiness.id
    }
    privateEndpointNetworkPolicies: 'Enabled'
    privateLinkServiceNetworkPolicies: 'Enabled'
    serviceEndpoints: [
      {
        service: 'Microsoft.Storage'
        locations: [ location ]
      }
      {
        service: 'Microsoft.Web'
      }
    ]
  }
}


resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2023-01-01' = {
  name: storageAccountName
  location: location
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
  properties: {
    supportsHttpsTrafficOnly: true
    minimumTlsVersion: 'TLS1_2'
    allowBlobPublicAccess: false
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Disabled'
    allowSharedKeyAccess: false
    networkAcls: {
      defaultAction: 'Deny'
      bypass: 'AzureServices'
      virtualNetworkRules: [
        {
          id: subnet.id
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

resource flexFuncPlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2023-12-01' = {
  name: planName
  location: location
  kind: 'functionapp'
  sku: {
    tier: 'FlexConsumption'
    name: 'FC1'
  }
  properties: {
    reserved: true
  }
}

var deploymentStorageContainerName = 'deploy-${functionAppName}'
resource functionApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2024-04-01' = {
  name: functionAppName
  location: location
  kind: 'functionapp,linux'
  identity: {
    type: 'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '${managedIdentity.id}': {}
    }
  }
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: flexFuncPlan.id
    virtualNetworkSubnetId: subnet.id
    siteConfig: {
      appSettings: [
        {
          name: 'AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName'
          value: storageAccount.name
        }
        {
          name: 'AzureWebJobsStorage__credential'
          value: 'managedidentity'
        }
        {
          name: 'AzureWebJobsStorage__clientId'
          value: managedIdentity.properties.clientId
        }
      ]
    }
    functionAppConfig: {
      deployment: {
        storage: {
          type: 'blobContainer'
          value: '${storageAccount.properties.primaryEndpoints.blob}${deploymentStorageContainerName}'
          authentication: {
            type: 'UserAssignedIdentity'
            userAssignedIdentityResourceId: managedIdentity.id
          }
        }
      }
      scaleAndConcurrency: {
        maximumInstanceCount: 100
        instanceMemoryMB: 2048
      }
      runtime: {
        name: 'dotnet-isolated'
        version: '8.0'
      }
    }
  }
}
var storageRoleDefinitionId = 'b7e6dc6d-f1e8-4753-8033-0f276bb0955b'
resource storageRoleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-04-01-preview' = {
  name: guid(storageAccount.id, storageRoleDefinitionId)
  scope: storageAccount
  properties: {
    roleDefinitionId: resourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', storageRoleDefinitionId)
    principalId: managedIdentity.properties.principalId
    principalType: 'ServicePrincipal'
  }
}




if you use service endpoint you need to enable publicNetworkAccess. publicNetworkAccess: 'Disabled' only works if you re using private endpoint.

also your function app should probably depends on storageRoleAssignment to make sure the role assignment has been created before creating the function.

Thanks for pointing that out. I fixed it, but still get the error :(

Internal server error is a temporary issue which can be occurred during bicep or ARM templates. To achieve your requirement, I have used below code and was able to perform the flex consumption plan deployment as expected.
param location string = 'eastus'
param functionPlanName string = 'asp-japroduct'
param functionAppName string = 'jahappprod'
param functionAppRuntime string = 'dotnet-isolated'
param functionAppRuntimeVersion string = '8.0'
param storageAccountName string = 'mystorejahst'
param logAnalyticsName string = 'worksjah'
param applicationInsightsName string = 'virtualinshg'
param maximumInstanceCount int = 100
param instanceMemoryMB int = 2048
param resourceNameNsgBusiness string = 'nsg-business-enb'
param vnetResourceName string = 'vnetlkenvironment'
param vnetAddressPrefix string = '10.0.0.0/16'
param subnetPrefixBusiness string = '10.0.1.0/24'
param resourceNameSubnetBusiness string = 'subnet--business'
var resourceToken = toLower(uniqueString(subscription().id, resourceGroup().name, location))
var deploymentStorageContainerName = 'app-package-${take(functionAppName, 32)}-${take(resourceToken, 7)}'
var storageRoleDefinitionId = 'b7e6dc6d-f1e8-4753-8033-0f276bb0955b'
resource nsgBusiness 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups@2024-01-01' = {
  name: resourceNameNsgBusiness
  location: location
}
resource vnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2024-01-01' = {
  name: vnetResourceName
  location: location
  properties: {
    addressSpace: {
      addressPrefixes: [
        vnetAddressPrefix
      ]
    }
    enableDdosProtection: false
    enableVmProtection: false
  }  
}
resource subnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets@2024-03-01' = {
  parent: vnet
  name: resourceNameSubnetBusiness
  properties: {
    addressPrefix: subnetPrefixBusiness
    networkSecurityGroup: {
      id: nsgBusiness.id
    }
    privateEndpointNetworkPolicies: 'Enabled'
    privateLinkServiceNetworkPolicies: 'Enabled'
    serviceEndpoints: [
      {
        service: 'Microsoft.Storage'
        locations: [ location ]
      }
      {
        service: 'Microsoft.Web'
      }
    ]
  }
}

resource logAnalytics 'microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces@2021-06-01' = {
  name: logAnalyticsName
  location: location
  properties: {
    retentionInDays: 30
    features: {
      searchVersion: 1
    }
    sku: {
      name: 'PerGB2018'
    }
  }
}

resource applicationInsights 'Microsoft.Insights/components@2020-02-02' = {
  name: applicationInsightsName
  location: location
  kind: 'web'
  properties: {
    Application_Type: 'web'
    WorkspaceResourceId: logAnalytics.id
  }
}

resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2023-01-01' = {
  name: storageAccountName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  properties: {
    accessTier: 'Hot'
    allowSharedKeyAccess: false
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled'
  }
}

resource storageAccountName_default 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices@2023-01-01' = {
  parent: storageAccount
  name: 'default'
}

resource storageAccountName_default_deploymentStorageContainer 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers@2023-01-01' = {
  parent: storageAccountName_default
  name: deploymentStorageContainerName
  properties: {
    publicAccess: 'None'
  }
}

resource functionPlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2023-12-01' = {
  name: functionPlanName
  location: location
  kind: 'functionapp'
  sku: {
    tier: 'FlexConsumption'
    name: 'FC1'
  }
  properties: {
    reserved: true
  }
}

resource functionApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2023-12-01' = {
  name: functionAppName
  location: location
  kind: 'functionapp,linux'
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: functionPlan.id
    functionAppConfig: {
      deployment: {
        storage: {
          type: 'blobContainer'
          value: 'concat(storageAccount.properties.primaryEndpoints.blob, deploymentStorageContainerName)'
          authentication: {
            type: 'SystemAssignedIdentity'
          }
        }
      }
      scaleAndConcurrency: {
        maximumInstanceCount: maximumInstanceCount
        instanceMemoryMB: instanceMemoryMB
      }
      runtime: {
        name: functionAppRuntime
        version: functionAppRuntimeVersion
      }
    }
    siteConfig: {
      appSettings: [
        {
          name: 'AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName'
          value: storageAccountName
        }
        {
          name: 'APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING'
          value: applicationInsights.id
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

resource Microsoft_Storage_storageAccounts_storageAccountName_storageRoleDefinitionId 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-04-01-preview' = {
  scope: storageAccount
  name: guid(storageAccount.id, storageRoleDefinitionId)
  properties: {
    roleDefinitionId: resourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', storageRoleDefinitionId)
    principalId: functionApp.identity.principalId
  }
}

Deployment succeeded:



Thanks for the suggestion, but here the function app is not in the subnet. When I use this example and add the subnet, I get the internal server error again.

Can you provide the snippet where it is failing exactly. @J.vanderHorst

Also please check this SO & blog here if it helps you. @J.vanderHorst

I added 2 screenshots of the errors: 1 in the pipeline and 1 in azure

is it working for you, when you add:
virtualNetworkSubnetId: subnet.id
to you function app properties? @jahnavi

Yes it worked for me. @J.vanderHorst

Can you try creating a new vnet and integrate it with function app again. It may be possible that the vnet in the subnet you are using has any restrictions.
